# I know RPMs can have build dependencies, but can they also have testing dependencies?

Tags: rpm, testing, rpm-spec

At work we are developing a number of different software tools in different repositories, which get packaged as RPM files. Our suite of test data for unit and integration testing has now grown to the gigabytes, and rather than bodily import that into every RPM, we would like to have a dependency that is only triggered when performing tests.

That is, some of our testers will not need the test-data repository. They will update the code repository, run rpmbuild --nocheck, and test the result by hand (such as user-interface testing, which we haven't automated).

Other folks in QA will download the code repository, run 'rpmbuild' and should be told if their installed test-data RPM is sufficiently recent or not.

For our production build robot, we want it to be able to examine the dependencies, download any needed updates, run all tests, and package the final output for shipment.

Is this even possible? The RPM specs I can find say almost nothing about testing environments, or use of %check.

Comment: *"we would like to have a dependency that is only triggered when performing tests"* - could you clarify that by editing your question, please? How does it work without RPM, how do you imagine it should work with RPM? This test data, does it relate to packages in terms of matching them?

Comment: Okay, I shall edit to try to clarify.